# Can't understand vagrant ssh implementation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vagrant

I recently start to use Vagrant (and recently move to Ubuntu from Windows too). My goal to understand fundamentals of `vagrant ssh`.

So, I'm trying to understand what `vagrant ssh` actually does.
I've read [What does `vagrant ssh` actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864372/what-does-vagrant-ssh-actually-do-how-can-i-reproduce-it-with-a-shell-script), but I haven't understood anything.

I'll try to explain with an example:

1. The first time, I connect into the vagrant machine by `ssh vagrant@192.168.0.x` and typing the password.
2. Next, I configure the keypair and connect into guest by `ssh vagrant@192.168.0.x` without typing password.
3. Next, I try to understand how vagrant implements SSH into its own guest machine:

   - In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, I set `PasswordAuthentication no`, but `vagrant ssh` still works
   - Delete **insecure_private_key** placed in `~/.vagrant.d` on the host machine, but vagrant restores it and `vagrant ssh` still works.
   - Remove `openssh-server` in the vagrant machine and now `vagrant ssh` really doesn't work :)

Please could anybody in plain English explain me how vagrant implements `vagrant ssh`?

---

Update: [Vagrant Docs: SSH](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) explains actually what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I didn't get the point of your question, but I'll try to explain you the main differences between `vagrant ssh` and `ssh`.

`vagrant ssh` is actually the same as a normal `ssh`, but there are several differences between them:

- port which ssh-client tries to access;
- private key that ssh-client uses for authentication;
- hosts-key is switched off for vagrant so you will not get initial message "The host is unknown";
- other minor differences.

If you know the port where vagrant runs, and know where is the private key that vagrant uses,
you can use `ssh` instead of `vagrant ssh`.

Comment: Вы случаем не русский?) May me I don't understand something, but is the ssh-client should use public key instead private key? As far as I know, private key are used on the machine we connect to, hence server and public key are used on the machine we connect from, hence client. In my mind `vagrant ssh` must use a public key. This moment confuse me..

Comment: The vargrant ssh wrapper uses a predefined ssh key (private). The virtual machine you are connecting to has a corresponding public key already installed in the vagrant users authorised keys file. So, when you use `vagrant ssh`, it doesn't require the password. It is also doing a bunch of other things as listed in this answer. The public key will be found in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov: Я русский, но тогда надо идти на другой сайт, здесь за такие шуточки сразу забивают. In the both cases are used private keys, the authentication procedure is the same; the point is that vargrant uses its own keys.

Comment: Интересно!)) Thank you Igor! I've got it, the problem was poor ssh knowledge.