# Remote script terminating prematurely after vagrant remote command

Tags: ssh, vagrant, bamboo

I have vagrant boxes configured on a remote server (`my-server` in my example). I'm trying to run a set of [remote commands on a vagrant box](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh.html), from my machine, through an SSH session:

```
ssh me@my-server << "ENDSSH"

    cd /dir/to/vagrant

    vagrant status my_box
    vagrant ssh my_box -- "ls"

    echo "Good bye!"

ENDSSH
```

The first 3 commands are executed correctly, but the forth command is never executed. After the output of `vagrant ssh my_box -- "ls"` is printed, the SSH session is closed. This happens for any command that I attempt to run on `my_box`.

If I create a script containing the above commands, log into `my-server` and run the script manually, all the commands are executed including `echo "Good bye!"`.

Is it possible that the `vagrant ssh my_box -- "ls"` produces an `EOF` which terminates the ssh session? Is there anyway to somehow catch the `EOF` token and then continue with the script?

**Note**:
This question relates to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34267246/bamboo-ssh-task-failing-java-lang-illegalstateexception) I asked regarding bamboo. The plugin in bamboo I used to execute remote commands produces an `Broken transport; encountered EOF` error after executing some remote tasks.

Comment: As a workaround, you might try exporting the vagrant ssh config to see if vanilla `ssh` avoids that hangup behavior http://stackoverflow.com/a/23685489/3385516

Comment: @mzulch thanks for the suggestion! Same behaviour though. This makes me think that ssh is to blame :/

Comment: Disabling reading from stdin with the -n switch seems to fix it (I tested with `ssh` directly but I think `vagrant ssh my_box -- -n "ls"` should behave the same way). I don't fully understand why it works so there may be caveats involved.

Comment: @mzulch that works with `vagrant ssh` as well! Seems like preventing it from reading from stdin fixes the issue! Thank you, if you answer I will gladly accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the outer ssh session from disconnecting by preventing the inner ssh command from reading from stdin, using the `-n` switch (for reference, [ssh man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh.1?query=ssh&sec=1))

```
vagrant ssh my_box -- -n "ls"
```