# vagrant up - server not starting because a ssh library issue

Tags: vagrant

I get this errormessage:

> An error occurred in the underlying SSH library that Vagrant uses. The
>   error message is shown below. In many cases, errors from this library
>   are caused by ssh-agent issues. Try disabling your SSH agent or
>   removing some keys and try again.

It is my first time with vagrant.

I took a tour through this tutorial.

https://wpbeaches.com/setting-up-a-wordpress-vvv-vagrant-workflow/

I've windows 10, vagrant 1.8.5, Oracle VM newest version.

I read a lot about this issue but nothing helps me.

Maybe somebody knows a solution.

Comment: have u tried as error message suggested. Kill the running ssh-agent process.

Comment: I don't have this process in my taskmanager. For info: vagrant ssh-config -> The port is 2200.. is that correct? I read the port should be 2222

Comment: 2222 is default one. please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864372/how-to-ssh-to-vagrant-without-actually-running-vagrant-ssh

Comment: Maybe these answers help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying

Answer (score 14):

Please try this command
**vagrant halt**
from inside your homestead directory
I had the same issue and this resolved my issue

Comment: This happened to me after the Win10 update came on 14/09/2018 for me, this answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

**1. vagrant halt**

**2. vagrant up --provision**