# Getting Bad configuration option: \377\376h

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

I am setting my systems for codecommit. but getting following error

I followed the below link : 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-windows.html

/c/Users/Prasanna/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: \377\376h
/c/Users/Prasanna/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options

here is the config file 
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  User ********
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa

Am I missing anything to configure ?

Answer (score 10):

Just had the same issue. Open the file with Notepad++. On the bottom right it tells you the encoding the file is in. It has to be `UTF-8 without BOM`. You can fix that via selecting a new encoding at the top and saving the file.

Comment: can do the same with VSCode: the key is to make sure it's UTF-8. When I re-opened the file that I had created as UTF-8, a bunch of weird chars were present and it was just a matter to delete them to get rid of the error

Comment: Yep, VSCode does it all :)

Answer (score 9):

You probably have some illegal characters in the `config` file. I had this problem while creating a `config` file on Windows. Unfortunately, simply opening the file in a Windows text editor may not show the illegal characters.

I was able to find this problem by running `cat filename` from a Bash prompt in Windows ([git bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win)) and was able to fix it by running `dos2unix filename` in `git bash`. The same may work for you as well.

Comment: Or opening in Webstorm (or equivalent) can reveal illegal characters like NBSP

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today, and I just recreated the config file and put my configs there, it works.